# JPA - How can I refer a column which is part of compound key in sub table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

How to map one of the column from compound field?

I have two tables Questions and Question_options.

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `question_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `question_options` (
  `question_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `option_id` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `option_description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`, `option_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_op_question_id` (`question_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_op_option_id` (`option_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_op_question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`question_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In Question.java:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
private List<QuestionOption> questionOptions;
```

In QuestionOption.java

```
@EmbeddedId
private QuestionOptionPK id;
```

In QuestionOptionPK.java

```
@Column(name="question_id", insertable=true, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
private long questionId;

@Column(name="option_id", insertable=true, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false, length=3)
private String optionId;
```

In Question.java, I am referring one of the fields of compound key(QuestionOptionPK) is questionId.

But I am getting error like this:

> SEVERE: Servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in web application [/SpringRestCrud] threw load() exception
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.mobily.model.QuestionOption column: question_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a derived identity.

Question.java:

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    @Column(name="question_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question")
    private List<QuestionOption> questionOptions;

    ...
}
```

QuestionOption.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="question_options")
public class Question {
    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionOptionPK id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    @MapsId("questionId") // maps questionId attribute of the embedded ID
    private Question question;

    ...
}
```

QuestionOptionPK.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionOptionPK {
    private long questionId; // corresponds to the PK type of Question

    @Column(name="option_id")
    private String optionId;
}
```

Derived identity is discussed in JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your solution but small problem. I changed same as you said here. But it became relationship between two tables is bi-directional. So I am getting same data again and again recursively.

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is now. Maybe you could give me a few more details?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my table structure. I removed compound primany key, instead of that I am using option_id as primary key, and now option_id is a numeric. I resolved.

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `question_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 -- `category` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
--  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
--  KEY `idx_fk_category` (`category`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `question_options` (
  `option_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `option_key` varchar(3) NOT NULL, -- It is like a, b, c... .
  `option_description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
--  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_op_question_id` (`question_id`),
--  KEY `idx_fk_op_option_id` (`option_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_op_question_id` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`question_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=601 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```